# Print out mario two half pyramid CS50

Tags: c, cs50

Hey I'm working on the CS50 more comfortable problem and I can't figure out how to print the second mario pyramid on the same line. In my code it already prints out, but it's not on the same line.

It doesn't matter if you guide me or show me how to do it. I'm using CS50 as a practice, I'm not turning anything in. So this wouldn't be cheating.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height = 0;

    // left pyramid variables
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    // variable for gap
    int g = 0;

    // right pyramid variables
    int l = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;


    //do - while loop -- works

    do
    {
        printf("Height: ");
        scanf("%d", &height);
    }

    while (height < 0 || height > 23);

    // Print pyramids

        // print spaces for left pyramid (less spaces needed with time) ✓
        // print hashes for left pyramid ✓
        // print gap (2)
        // print hashes for right pyramid
        // print new line - for next row

    // Left Pyramid

    // Rows -- determines the height
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Cols -- in this one we are doing the spaces

        // the -i makes it left aligned -- to make it right aligned remove the "-1"
        for (j = 0; j < height-i; j++)
        {
            // Printing Spaces
            printf(" ");
        }
        // "i+1" - we want i to be 1 whenever height is 0, and we want i to increase by one
        // whenever the height increases, so that's why we add + 1 to it
        // if I don't add 1 to it what it does is that prints a new line, and then it prints
        // 4 things instead of 5 for example.
        for (k = 0; k < i + 1; k++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        // Print new line
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Gap -- fix gap, the rest works how it should -- I think I need to make everything
    // inside one loop

    // for (g = 0; g < height; g++)
    // {
    //     printf("  ");
    // }

    // Right Pyramid

      // Rows -- determines the height
    for (l = 0; l < height; l++)
    {

        // Cols -- in this one we are doing the spaces

        // right aligned
        for (m = 0; m < height; m++)
        {
            // Printing Spaces
            printf(" ");
        }
        // "i+1" - we want i to be 1 whenever height is 0, and we want i to increase by one
        // whenever the height increases, so that's why we add + 1 to it
        // if I don't add 1 to it what it does is that prints a new line, and then it prints
        // 4 things instead of 5 for example.
        for (n = 0; n < l + 1; n++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        // Print new line
        printf("\n");
     }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: name variables appropriately: rather than a comment that states " // variable for gap" .. call the variable 'gap'! Or something even more descriptive

Comment: I'm drowning in code comments!!

Comment: Since a newline ends a line, with no option to go back to the previous line (well, not using the basics), you'll simply have to print out left and right at the same time.

Comment: There's a bunch of questions (with answers) related to CS50 Mario pyramids popping up in the "related" section; have you checked any of those?

Comment: @Evert how I do that? And yes I checked those. People decided to do the normal version. I haven't found one that has the more comfortable version which is this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do something like into the first loop:

```
for (k = 0; k < i + 1; k++)
{
    printf("#");
}

/* this is new */
/* Draw the gap */
for (k = 0; k < gap; k++) {
    printf(" ");
}
/* Draw the left part*/
for (k = 0; k < i + 1; k++)
{
    printf("#");
}
```

Comment: I'll try that. I also have to include the spaces between each # and then two space gap between the left and right pyramid. Thanks for your input. I appreciate it

Comment: Thanks for that. It worked. The only thing that's not working is the two space gap between the two pyramids. But the rest works :D

Can you help me with the two space gap?

Comment: NVM I figured the gap out 

I did the following:

for (k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
    printf("  ");
}